# Ошибка создания COM HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

Tags: c#, c++, com

Не получается создать объект класса Com IShellWindows. На примере документации С++ создание работает. Но при попытке создать его в С#. Получаю исключение.

```
static Guid CLSID_IShellWindows = new Guid("85CB6900-4D95-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85");
static Guid IID_ShellWindows = new Guid("9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39");


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type desktopType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_IShellWindows, null, true);
    object shellDesktop = Activator.CreateInstance(desktopType);
}
```

Type возвращается, но его не возможно создать через Activator. Поиск по ошибке говорит сменить целевой процессор на x86, но это не помогает.

Comment: Возможно это уже есть https://csharp.hotexamples.com/ru/examples/-/ShellWindows/-/php-shellwindows-class-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Вы откуда-то взяли неверные идентификаторы и, таким образом, пытаетесь создать объект по идентификатору интерфейса. Вот так сработает:

```
Guid CLSID_ShellWindows = new Guid("9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39");
object shellDesktop = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_ShellWindows, null, true));
```

Comment: Там суть в том, что что идентификаторы то верные. Есть ShellWindows (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/shell/shellwindows), а есть IShellWindows (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/exdisp/nn-exdisp-ishellwindows). Да действительно не создать интерфейс IShellWindows, но можно объект ShellWindows привести IShellWindows. И оно работает.

Comment: Идентификаторы в вопросе неверные, у меня в фрагменте кода - верный. Проверяется это [по Windows 10 SDK](https://github.com/Empyreal96/Easy-Build-2k/blob/36fce23389e43918faf4cd88688c64aa2668ff8f/NT/public/sdk/inc/exdisp.idl#L559), или [можно ещё так](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=CLSID_ShellWindows).

Comment: Посмотри я пытался создать IShellWindows, а надо ShellWindows создать и привести к IShellWindows. И в моем фрагменте кода указан тот же Guid, что и в твоем ответе. Меня интересовал IShellWindows. Я как раз использовал MagNumDB для поиска Guid.

Comment: Идентификатор не тот же. Вообще нет такого "CLSID_IShellWindows", CLSID_ это идентификатор класса (coclass), а _IShellWindows относится к интерфейсу. Правильно CLSID_ShellWindows, IID_IShellWindows, а не CLSID_IShellWindows, IID_ShellWindows.

Comment: Действительно наоборот написал. CLSID у ShellWindows должен быть, IShellWindows IID.  CLSID GUID COM-класс, а IID интерфейса. Вроде так?  Идентификаторы(тe что GUIDы) верные.

Comment: Когда идентификаторы верные, то дальше все по-обычному. CLSID используется для создания (co-creation) экземпляра, а у этого экземпляра можно запросить интерфейс по IID интерфейса.

Comment: Посни пожалуйста что ты имеешь ввиду под "запросить интерфейс по IID". Просто мне известен только способ представления управляемой оболочки интерфейса.

Comment: Для C# само по себе объявление IID не имеет большого смысла потому что отсутствует опредление самого интерфейса, что-то [вроде этого](https://github.com/shibayan/WinQuickLook/blob/ad7f672f3237080681d533c2d83a77984e295444/WinQuickLook.CsWin32/IShellWindows.cs#L7). Или нужен эквивалентный импорт определения интерфейса из библиотеки типов. Когда же есть интерфейс с ассоциированным с ним IID, тогда нет нужды объявлять  `IID_IShellWindows`, потому что можно уже просто сделать `shellDesktop as IShellWindows` (к примеру).

Comment: Так IID надо объявлять в оболочке класса интерфейса, что то вроде `[ComImport, Guid("..."), InterfaceType]`